# Albert classification of rational endomorphism rings of simple Abelian varieties over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Recall the Albert classification of rational endomorphism rings with involution of simple Abelian varieties over arbitrary fields:

- Type I: totally real, trivial involution
- Type II and III: quaternion algebras over totally real number fields
- Type IV: center is a CM field for which the restriction of the involution is complex conjugation

Now my question is: Which of these division algebras can actually occur if the *base field is a finite field*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.math.nyu.edu/~tschinke/books/finite-fields/final/05_oort.pdf, Section 15:

Only Type III and IV can occur, and III only for dimension $1$ or $2$.